# Android SDK - App doesn't read php/MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, sdk

as i said in the title

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.achkars.espaceado"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.achkars.espaceado.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.achkars.espaceado;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webview);
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        // Simplest usage: note that an exception will NOT be thrown
         // if there is an error loading this page (see below).
         webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And the file News.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/style.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<img alt="full screen background image" src="file:///android_asset/back.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" />
<center><img alt="up" src="file:///android_asset/top.png" id="up" /> </center>
<center><img alt="down" src="file:///android_asset/down.png" id="down"/></center>
<h2><center>
Les nouvelles (Blagues)
</center></h2>
<ul>
<a href="file:///android_asset/index.html"><li class="arrow">La page precedente</li></a>
</ul>
<ul>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("The Domain","Username","Password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("DB Name", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM espace");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "<a href=".$row['link'].">","<li class=".$row['arrow'].">";
echo $row['news'];
echo "</li></a>";
  };
mysql_close($con);
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

On PC it is working normaly but on phone i am getting:

```
"," ";echo $row['news'}; echo " 
";}; mysql_close($con); ?>
```

Does it need any permission?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Are you seriously trying to interpret a `.php` file on an Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android cannot run PHP code on the device itself. PHP is a server side language, and you will have to move all PHP functionality onto a webserver, and access it through that.

Do note that there is a [PHP for Android](http://phpforandroid.net/) project which you may be able to use to run the code locally, but I am not sure how complete or active the port is.

Comment: So i should make an iframe?

Comment: @AlexandreAchkar Not exactly what I meant, but as long as the PHP code is on a webserver that supports PHP, and you are loading that into the iFrame it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

A php page is a script, which need a PHP interpreter to be parsed and to be properly displayed. You can't have this in your Android (and it's not what you really want). You need to store this script in a webserver with PHP compatibility and see it via internet through the phone's browser (again, i suppose that this isn't what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Get a web server for Android, move your php script to the `htdocs` (or other) document folder and everything will run fine when invoked as `localhost:8080/` . I use KSWeb server on both smartphone and tablet with no problems.